# Does the "condition" (? :) operator work in JavaScript as in C?

Tags: javascript, c, operators, ternary-operator, conditional-operator

Example:

```
var x, y, z;
//...
x > 100 ? y = x : z = x ;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it does work the same although operator precedence is always tricky so I would recommend parenthesis to avoid confusion.

tangentially related..
You can also use `||` in JavaScript similar to the null coalescing operator `??` in C#

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this works:

```
x > 100 ? y = x : z = x ;
```

But this works:

```
y = x > 100 ? foo : bar ;
```

Comment: Tested it out. Looks like it does work. `var z = 0; var y = 0; var x = 10; x > 100 ? y = x : z = x;` You get `x:10, y:0, z:10`.

Comment: Your example doesn't accomplish the same thing as the original code

Answer (score 1):

Yes, ternary operators work the same way [in Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#conditional_operator). Your example is combining a lot of expressions, so [precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) might be an issue. You should parenthesize to ensure precedence.

Answer (score 1):

This should help you (in the future):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence

First of all the `>` comparison will be evaluated because it has precedence 8. `?:` has precedence 15, lower than 16 for `=`. This means that the ternary operator will be run before any assignments (i.e. the first operand, the condition, will be evaluated and then only a branch will be chosen).

Also a simple test

```
//x = 50;
x = 200;
x > 100 ? y = x : z = x ;
alert((typeof y)+'|'+(typeof z));
```

would have answered you question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it works the same in that it has the following basic syntax

```
condition ? true-expression : false-expression
```

It only evaluates the expression, and hence processes side effects, for the expression dictated by the conditional.

Here's a link to the Mozilla documentation on the ternary operator

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special/Conditional_Operator

Answer (score 1):

Yes, ternary operators work the same way in Javascript as they do in C, C++, C#, Java, Javascript, Perl, and PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, according to the [conditional operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_operator) Wikipedia article and the [ECMA-262](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-262.pdf) standard (see section 11.12).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a different approach. You can use the ternary to select the variable as a string within square brackets.

This `window` assumes `y` and `z` are global. Otherwise, you would need to give the proper context.

```
window[x > 100 ? 'y' : 'z'] = x;
```